# Entity Framework 6 insert into table with existing data throws DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm using C# with Entity Framework 6 and MSSQL Server.
I'm trying to insert data into a table with existing historical data.
Below is a snippet of the code, but I get an DbUpdateException "Violation of Primary Key Constraint".
I checked the SQL table and EDMX, and both have the correct ID column as an Identity column.
Also, the EDMX's SSDL and CSDL are correctly set with "identity".

Update: the SQL table already has data, but the SaveChanges() tries to insert into this table with identity starting from 0, ignoring the existing data, causing this PK constraint violation error.

Please assist.

```
public int PersistEntity(T entity)
{
    var newRecords = 0;
    using (var context = new myEntities())
    {
        using (var dbcontext = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var entity = new tblEntity();
            // ...
            context.tblEntities.Add(entity);
            //context.tblEntities.Attach(entity); // also tried this without success.

            try
            {
                newRecords = context.SaveChanges();
                dbcontext.Commit();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                throw; // thrown on context.SaveChanges()
            }
        }
    }
    return newRecords;
}
```

Here is the code for tblEntity:

```
namespace MyLibrary.Infrastructure.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblEntity
    {
        public tblEntity()
        {
            this.tblCalibrations = new HashSet<tblCalibration>();
            this.tblOutput = new HashSet<tblOutput>();
        }

        public int iID { get; set; }
        public string cPlateName { get; set; }
        public int iInstrument { get; set; }
        public int iStatus { get; set; }
        public int iTest { get; set; }

        public virtual tblTest tblTest { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblCalibration> tblCalibrations { get; set; }
        public virtual tblInstrument tblInstrument { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<tblOutput> tblOutput { get; set; }
        public virtual tblStatus tblStatus { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to debug, use SQL Server Profiler to see what queries are executed against your database.

Comment: What is the primary key for `tblEntity`?

Comment: Where is the PK set?

Comment: It's in the SQL table as well as with a constraint. Also I checked in the EDMX model that the iID column on tblEntity is an int with Identity as the StoreGeneratedPattern option.

Comment: And in your model, the `iID` column is marked as an entity key?

Comment: Yes, the EDMX designer model for tblEntity, iID column is Int32, Entity = True, StoreGeneratedPattern = Identity

Comment: And it doesn't have a default value?

Comment: In the model iID has no default value. Problem? (Sorry I don't have enough points to go onto chat).